# Domain of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following differential equation

$$
y' + \frac{1}{t-2}y = 7(t-2)^2y^{1/2} \tag{1}
$$

Because it's a Bernoulli equation, by multiplying with $y^{-1/2}$ we get

$$
y^{-1/2}y' + \frac{1}{t-2}y^{1/2} = 7(t-2)^2 
$$

and if we let $u = y^{1/2}$ with $u' = \frac{1}{2}y^{-1/2}y'$ we have

$$
u' + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{t-2}u = \frac{7}{2}(t-2)^2. \tag{2}
$$

To find the integrating factor we have

$$
\mu(t) = e^{\int \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{t-2} dt} = e^{ \frac{1}{2} \ln |t-2| } = |t-2|^{1/2}.
$$

So now, we have to multiply $(2)$ by $\mu(t)$. But how can we tell if $t \geq 2$ or not?

Comment: That would depend on your initial conditions. Your ode has a singularity at $t=2$ thus care must be taken here. Without any initial conditions each case must be considered separately.

Answer (score 1):

Given $u^\prime + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{t-2}u = \frac{7}{2}(t-2)^2$ with integrating factor $\mu=\vert t-2\vert^{1/2}$ it matters only that $t\ne2$.
\begin{align}
\vert t-2\vert ^{1/2}u^\prime+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{\vert t-2\vert ^{1/2}}{t-2\phantom{^{1/2}}}u &= \frac{7}{2}(t-2)^2\vert t-2\vert ^{1/2}\\
\left(\vert t-2\vert ^{1/2}u\right)^\prime &= \frac{7}{2}(t-2)^2\vert t-2\vert ^{1/2}\\
\vert t-2\vert ^{1/2}u &= (t-2)^3\vert t-2\vert ^{1/2}+C\\
u &= (t-2)^2+C\,\vert t-2\vert ^{-1/2}\\
y &=\left[(t-2)^2+C\,\vert  t-2\vert ^{-1/2}\right]^2
\end{align}